# How can i implement hashCode() when i override equals() from Object class

Tags: java, android

in java PMD rules, there is a rule OverrideBothEqualsAndHashcode.

it means that developer has to override both equals(Object obj) and hashCode() not just one.

can someone explain why?

and if i override and re-define eqauls(Object obj), what should i implement in hashCode() ?

```
class MyClass() {
    public int id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return id == ((MyClass) obj).id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // WHAT KIND OF CODE SHOULD I IMPLEMENT HERE?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override `equals`, you must override `hashCode`, since the contract of `hashCode` requires that equal objects have the same `hashCode`.

As for the `hashCode` implementation of your particular example, that's simple. Since your equality is determined by a single `int` instance variable, `hashCode` should simply return that variable.

This gives you the best possible `hashCode` implementation - non equal `MyClass` instances will never have the same `hashCode`.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id;
}
```